# How to download a file from internet explorer using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to download an excel workbook from Internet Explorer 11 and when I click on the link, this pop up message appears:

[image]

I've tried to use sendkeys "%s" and it didn't work. I can't use the code to download a file from the internet without using IE because the URL is an intranet site from my company.

```
Sub Site()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://asint010/IntegradorProfit/Pages/Relatorios/FluxoSolicitacao.aspx"

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        .document.All("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnexportar").Click
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

       'here I don't know what to do

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I hope you find an answer. I have tried to do this countless times to no avail. You ultimately need to communicate with the Save As dialog box, or other IE controls that I was never able to get to work.

Comment: this is almost asked daily.  Use the search bar, upper right hand corner, and search download, internet, vba

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code to download the file. You need to change the code as per your language settings. Also you can remove some of the declare function lines which are not required for you.

```
Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageByString Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function SetFocus Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Integer

    Sub Site()
        Dim IE As Object
        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
        With IE
            .Visible = True
            .Navigate "http://asint010/IntegradorProfit/Pages/Relatorios/FluxoSolicitacao.aspx"

            While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
                DoEvents
            Wend

            .document.All("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnexportar").Click
            While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
                DoEvents
            Wend

           'here I don't know what to do
            hpass = IE.hWnd
            DownloadFile (hpass)

        End With
    End Sub

    Sub DownloadFile(h As Long)
        Dim o As IUIAutomation
        Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
        Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
        Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
        Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern

        Set o = New CUIAutomation
        h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
        If h = 0 Then Exit Sub

        Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
        Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")
        Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
        Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
        InvokePattern.Invoke

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Close")
        Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
        Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
        InvokePattern.Invoke
    End Sub
```