# NSE India Quote History Download Automation

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

first of all I'm not a programmer, I just want to Download A quote history from https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm by putting some input data in Excel. I somehow managed to put data in VBA. Could anyone please help me how to click on "Download File in CSV Format" & save it to my local disk.

Here is my VBA code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim IE As Object
  With IE
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'create new instance of IE. use reference to return current open IE if
'you want to use open IE window. Easiest way I know of is via title bar.
  IE.Navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm"
'go to web page listed inside quotes
  IE.Visible = True
  While IE.busy
    DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
  Wend
  IE.document.ALL("symbol").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("b1")
  IE.document.ALL("series").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("b2")

  IE.document.getElementById("rdDateToDate").Click

  IE.document.ALL("fromDate").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("b4")

  IE.document.ALL("toDate").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("c4")
  IE.document.getElementById("submitMe").Click

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide the values for `Symbol` and `Series`? Ideal your `From Date` and `To Date` as well but they are not critical

Comment: Symbol=SBIN, Series=EQ, From date=01-01-2012 & To Date=01-12-2012

Comment: And please provide the code which will automatically close the IE after downloading the file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below UDF will do what you are looking for:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim oW As Worksheet: Set oW = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    Dim oEleCol As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 
    Dim oEle As MSHTML.IHTMLElement


    With IE
    'Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

        ' Set IE
        .Visible = True
        'ShowWindow .hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED

        ' Navigate to URL
        .Navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm"

        ' Wait for page to be ready
        While .Busy
          DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
        Wend

        ' Set criteria
        .document.all("symbol").Value = oW.Range("I2")
        .document.all("series").Value = oW.Range("I3")
        .document.getElementById("rdDateToDate").Click

        ' Wait for page to be ready
        While .Busy
          DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
        Wend

        ' Set remaining criteria
        .document.all("fromDate").Value = oW.Range("I4")
        .document.all("toDate").Value = oW.Range("I5")

        ' Submit criteria
        .document.getElementById("submitMe").Click

        ' Wait for page to be ready
        While .Busy
          DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
        Wend

        ' Find the link to download file
        Set oEleCol = .document.getElementsByTagName("A")
        For Each oEle In oEleCol
            If oEle.innerText = "Download file in csv format" Then
                oEle.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        ' Wait for page to be ready
        While .Busy
          DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
        Wend

        ' Download file
        DownloadFile .hwnd

        ' Close IE
        .Quit

    End With

End Sub
```

**NOTE:**
1. You can comment out this line as I use it to maximise the browser window: `ShowWindow .hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED`
2. **`DownloadFile`** is a function call. You can find the function here: [How to download a file from internet explorer using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983302/how-to-download-a-file-from-internet-explorer-using-vba)
3. Change the sheet name to whatever your sheet is
4. Change the cell references to whatever your references are

Comment: I suspect it's IE object that's throwing the error. That is because I am using `Microsoft Internet Controls` where you were creating an IE object. Reference the above control by clicking the `Tools` menu, then `References`. This will open a window. Scroll down until you find `Microsoft Internet Controls`, select it and then press `OK` button. This should resolve the issue

Comment: I've updated the code so that you wont get those errors any more. Don't forget to get the **DownloadFile** function from the link I provided

Comment: I don't figure it out what code to enter in DownloadFile link. Could you please help me to what code to include.

Comment: I tried to launch the code without DownloadFile code & it worked though it didn't popup file download option i.e code didn't click on "Download file in csv format".