# Trouble with automated download from secure website

Tags: ms-access, internet-explorer, vba

I'm looking for some assistance in downloading files from a secure website. I don't have much knowledge in this area so I'm not sure what I can provide that will be helpful. If you can tell me what to grab from the website I will.

Here are the basics. I must use IE. I'm using vba to send the automated code. I can login to the website, navigate to their reports page, run my report. It returns a table with a hyperlink, name etc. I'm only at the stage of trying to download just one example so I know the download works. I think I'll be able to loop the table & feed hyperlinks to the loop without a problem.

When I fed the download code its first hyperlink, I got my pdf but upon opening it it is only a message saying you must be logged in to view. Well I was logged in. That used

```
Call URLDownloadToFile(0, "https://atlasbridge.com/reports/atlasreportdownload.ashx?N=49837661&RT=PREVMAIL", "C:\Users\JCarney\Desktop\DownloadedMail\atlasreportdownload.ashx.pdf", 0, 0)
```

then I tried:

```
 Dim theURL As String
 theURL = "https://atlasbridge.com/reports/atlasreportdownload.ashx?  N=49837661&RT=PREVMAIL"          
Debug.Print theURL
Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", theURL, False, UName, Pword
WinHttpReq.Send
theURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
Debug.Print theURL
Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oStream.Open
oStream.Type = 1
oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody oStream.SaveToFile "C:\Users\JCarney\Desktop\DownloadedMail\atlasreportdownload.ashx.pdf", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
oStream.Close
End If
```

The result is the same, a pdf downloads but says I'm not logged in. UName, Pword are string variables that look up the user name & password earlier in the sub. They are looking up the correct info. I'm at a loss as to where to go from here. Can I make vba "click" the hyperlink & download & name the file? or do I continue trying to download from WinHttpReq.

here is what the html of the table looks like:

```
 '<table align="center" id="ctl00_cphMain_dgMailings" style="border-collapse:collapse;" border="1" rules="all" cellspacing="0">
'<td>Policy</td><td>Insured</td><td>Type</td><td>Mailed</td>
'    <tbody><tr class="blacktextbold">
'        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>Policy</td><td>Insured</td><td>Type</td><td>Mailed</td>
'    </tr><tr class="blacktext">

'    </tr><tr class="blacktext" style="background-color:#D9D9D9;">
'        <td><a href="../reports/atlasreportdownload.ashx?N=49837661&amp;RT=PREVMAIL" target="_blank">View</a></td><td>1501-1603-1276</td><td>SUSAN</td><td>Amended Dec Page</td><td>12/08/2018</td>
'    </tr><tr class="blacktext">href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$dgMailings$ctl19$ctl01','')">&gt;</a></td>
'    </tr>
'</tbody></table>
```

What the properly formatted hyperlink will be, as if you did this manually is:
"https://atlasbridge.com/reports/atlasreportdownload.ashx?N=49837661&RT=PREVMAIL"
The table is showing us the truncated path.

Thank you in advance.

quick edit. When I inspect the element, the "view" hyperlink in the table. I get:

```
<a href="../reports/atlasreportdownload.ashx?N=49988945&amp;RT=PREVMAIL" target="_blank">View</a>
```

If that's helpful. Doesn't shed any light for me but maybe it's helpful.
This is the response text if i use SetCredentials "username","password",, HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER for the login screen of the website
[login screen webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In7GN.png)

here's the response text when i hit the pdf hyperlink directly:
[pdf hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtnch.png)

Comment: What if you try to download the PDF report files manually from the browser? Is that display the same error message or opens the PDF file successfully? It is possible that there is some logic applied by that site and it only opens the file in browser if user is logged in.

Comment: Manual download is how we do it now. But I have also tested the login aspect of the code is working by letting that run & grabbing a file. We just click the view hyperlink & the pdf display's fine in another tab or you can right click it & save it directly. So it definitely see's I'm logged in, the manual way. That all works well. So I'm thinking I either need to automate the "click - save" steps or still do a silent download but pass it the credentials each time, which i don't know how to do. I'm ok with either method.

Comment: I did just try a test on this theory. I logged in. opened a document by Clicking on view. Of course that worked. I copied the hyperlink though & pasted it into another tab, while I'm logged in and it did pull the document successfully, so it is not just clicking on the document that pulls it.And a second test, open a new tab in it's own browser window & paste the hyperlink and that worked too. So IE thru more manual methods seems to still provide to the document server that it's me logged in.

Comment: I added to png files showing the response text I get when use setcredentials on the login page and on the pdf hyperlink in their website.

Answer (score 0):

From your last post, I can see that your manual steps are working.

But, In your code you are using **WinHttpReq.Open** and other code. Which will not work exactly as you did manually.

I suggest you to create an object of Internet Explorer and than try to use it to open your web page. than you can try to find the PDF file links using its id and try to click the buttons or links to download it.

Example code:

```html
Sub demo()
            
        Dim IEapp As Object
        Dim WebUrl As String
        
        Set IEapp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
        WebUrl = "http://www.microsoft.com"
                                                                                       
        With IEapp
            .Silent = True
            .Visible = True
            .Navigate WebUrl


            Do While .Busy
                DoEvents
            Loop
            
            Do While .readyState <> 4
                DoEvents
            Loop
        
        End With
               
    End Sub
```

Add reference to **Microsoft Internet Controls** and **Microsoft HTML Object Library** to run this code.

This is just an example code, you need to modify it and add more code to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. Assuming I navigate to the page successfully, which I can do how do I save the pdf file? I'm assuming I'll be able to click the hyperlink in the code just with ".click" on the element. I've been thru the object browser but dont see a save/save as type command. I do think I'll be able to use shell to get over to the correct tab. I think i can have it loop open items till it matches the URL. I'll know the URL from the element so that'll be ok.

Comment: You can try to refer the code example of the answer in the following thread to get the information about the code to download the files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983302/how-to-download-a-file-from-internet-explorer-using-vba

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll check it out & post back, most likely I won't get a crack at it til after the holiday but i'll let you know. Thank you very much for the advice!